Understanding the relationship between $\Delta G$ and $K_p$, $K_x$ and $K_c$
Upon reading the chapter about equilibrium from my physical chemistry book, I was convinced that
$$ΔG= -RT \text{ln}(K_p) \tag{1}$$
and that
$$K_p = K_x (P^{\sum v}) \tag{2}$$
where $K_p$ is the equilibrium constant with respect to pressure and $K_x$ is the equilibrium constant with respect to molar fraction.
However, I was not convinced of
$$ΔG= -RT\text{ln}(K_x)$$
As it would have made more sense that given (1) and (2), that:
$$ΔG= -RT\text{ln}(K_x (P^{\sum v})) $$
So what am I missing that made me unable to understand how this derivation came to be?
Same for Kc, where:
$$Kp= Kc (\left(RT\right)^{\sum v})$$
yet
$$ΔG= -RT\text{ln}(Kc)$$
